# Implementing Real Time application using Redis and Faye

Tags: php, ruby, redis, real-time, faye

I need to develop a realtime notification system. Load won't be high, about a dozen of events per hour. But I just want to make it scalable for future development.

My application is written entirely in `PHP`.

I have found different ways of implementing real-time applications. And I think the following architecture is quite simple and have a lot of benefits.

[image: Real Time Ruby Architecture]

But I want to use the `Faye` library for implementing real time notifications, because it has fallbacks, and generally I am not going to use `Websockets` because my load is really low, and at first I will stick to the `long-polling` mechanism. `Faye` provides a convenient way for disabling and enabling different transport protocols.

Here is how my architecture is going to look

[image]

However I have one question regarding communicating back from a client.

Consider the following case.

1. Client loads a page through plain old `HTTP` request to a `PHP` app
2. Client side script opens a websocket/long polling connection
3. Another person sends notification via posting it through a simple `AJAX` request
4. This notification is saved to a database and assigned to a target recipient.
5. Notification is posted to a `Redis` database and consumed by `Faye`
6. Notification is sent to a client, everything is fine.

So far so good, but I need to some sort of back communication, for example when a client dismisses an event. 
How should this be implemented, should I send this action back using `Faye` or this should be sent directly to the `PHP` application. In case of sending an event back using `Faye` I need to notify my `PHP` application that an event was seen and dismissed. Of course I can use the same database from a Ruby application as used by PHP app, but this makes these two application coupled.

Could you suggest a right way to implement this ?

Comment: I am not sure why one there is a PHP app in one graph but a Rails App in the other. But when you use I suggest to have a look at the [Rails Guide about Action Cable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html).

Comment: SO is more about providing help with specific coding problems, you are asking for guidance on how to start.  If you have some code and are having difficulties getting it working then that is a more suitable question- IMHO.